# Display select event from full calendar into popup

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to use full calendar to select a date and to use the data it in a popup box where someone can verify the date/time and change the line of text

Nb in the below code alert(start); displays the correctly selected date and time
eg Sat Feb 02 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000

However when trying to put it in an editable textbox the data in 'start' is not being sent as a variable in the line

```
'<input class="form-control" type="text" value="start" id="start" >'+
```

full code:

```
initFullCalendar: function(){

    $calendar = $('#fullCalendar');

    today = new Date();
    y = today.getFullYear();
    m = today.getMonth();
    d = today.getDate();

    $calendar.fullCalendar({
        select: function(start, end) {

        alert(start);

            // on select we show the Sweet Alert modal with an input
            swal({

                title: 'Create x Event',
                html: '<div class="form-group">' +
                        '<input class="form-control" placeholder="Facility" id="facility">' +
                    '</div>'+
                '<div class="form-group">' +
                        '<input class="form-control" placeholder="Provider" id="provider">' +
                    '</div>' +
                '<div class="form-group">' +
                        '<input class="form-control" placeholder="Complaint" id="starttime">' +
                    '</div>'+
                '<div class="form-group">' +
                   '<label for="Category">Select </label>' +
                   '<select class="form-control" id="category">' +
                   '<option>New Patient</option>' +
                   '<option>Review</option>' +
                   '<option>Referral</option>' +
                   '<option>Urgent Request</option>' +
                   '</select>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="form-group">' +
    '<input class="form-control" type="text" value=start id="start" >'+

                   '</div>',

                showCancelButton: true,
```

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you're actually trying to do here? You mention about parameters but I don't see anywhere that you try to use the `start` and `end` in your popup. Did you mean to set the value of start into the `input id="start"` control that you're generating? if so then you need to set the `value` attribute of that element e.g. `'<input class="form-control" type="text" id="start" value="' + start.format() + '"/>'`...something like that. Adjust the [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to your requirements. (N.B. your input control was also missing its "type")

Comment: I edited the post a bit , hope this is clearer

Comment: Take a look at the example in my comment a little more closely. In your version you're passing the plain string "start", because it's just part of the rest of the string. In my version I'm using the actual _variable_ called start, by stopping the string, adding the (formatted version of) the variable to it, and then re-starting the string again. (i.e. "string concatenation")

Comment: ok this works , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value attribute of that element using the actual "start" *variable*, by concatenating (joining) it with rest of the string. Right now you're just including a static string called "start". e.g.

```
'<input class="form-control" type="text" id="start" value="' + start.format() + '"/>'
```

Note that the string ends, the start value is joined on using the `+` symbols, and then the string restarts again.

N.B. You can adjust the format of the date to your requirements - check the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).